# select profile from environment maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit

We need to set a maven profile trough IntelliJ ideas job configuration for a JUnit test suite but we are not able to pass the profile trough the arguments list. Is it possible to select maven profile trough setting an environment variable like `PROFILE=test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use an environment variable try this (from [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)):

```
<profiles>
   <profile>
      <activation>
         <property>
            <name>env.PROFILE</name>
            <value>SOME_ENVIRONMENT</value>
         </property>
      </activation>
      <!-- ... -->
   </profile>
</profiles>
```

To use a system property `PROFILE` just drop the `env.`.